# Applying RT PREEMPT kernel patch fails

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, patch, real-time

I am trying to apply the RT PREEMPT patch for the Linux kernel. 
As mentioned in guides like [this](http://www.frank-durr.de/?p=203) and [this](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/realtime/documentation/howto/applications/preemptrt_setup), you are supposed to do it like this:

```
zcat patch-4.14.15-rt13.patch.gz | patch -p1
```

(assuming that you are in the directory containing the kernel sources.)

But I get a lot of messages like:

```
The next patch would create the file tools/testing/selftests/ftrace/test.d/trigger/inter-event/trigger-synthetic-event-createremove.tc,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
patching file virt/kvm/arm/arm.c
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
3 out of 3 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file virt/kvm/arm/arm.c.rej
```

And in the end the process fails. I have tried this in an `ubuntu:16.04` and a `debian:stretch` docker container, the result was the same.

I can not interact with the patching process btw because it is part of a bash script.

I am applying the patch on the [kernel sources for the Raspberry Pi](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux) btw.

Here is the [complete patch output](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/21a3949759f1d51ed01966a8d4b1dfab/raw/876f2262833076e1c69dd12460cdcbef5091a9ac/gistfile1.txt).

What am I doing wrong? How can I apply the patch correctly?

The contents of `virt/kvm/arm/arm.c.rej` are:

```
--- virt/kvm/arm/arm.c
+++ virt/kvm/arm/arm.c
@@ -650,7 +650,7 @@ int kvm_arch_vcpu_ioctl_run(struct kvm_vcpu *vcpu, struct kvm_run *run)
         * involves poking the GIC, which must be done in a
         * non-preemptible context.
         */
-       preempt_disable();
+       migrate_disable();

        kvm_pmu_flush_hwstate(vcpu);

@@ -687,7 +687,7 @@ int kvm_arch_vcpu_ioctl_run(struct kvm_vcpu *vcpu, struct kvm_run *run)
            kvm_pmu_sync_hwstate(vcpu);
            kvm_timer_sync_hwstate(vcpu);
            kvm_vgic_sync_hwstate(vcpu);
-           preempt_enable();
+           migrate_enable();
            continue;
        }

@@ -742,7 +742,7 @@ int kvm_arch_vcpu_ioctl_run(struct kvm_vcpu *vcpu, struct kvm_run *run)

        kvm_vgic_sync_hwstate(vcpu);

-       preempt_enable();
+       migrate_enable();

        ret = handle_exit(vcpu, run, ret);
    }
```

after the build.

Comment: The preempt patch you have is for kernel version 4.14.15 - make sure you check out the 4.14.y branch of the Raspberry Pi kernel (i.e. [this](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/tree/rpi-4.14.y)) - and even then you might have problems (but they might be easily fixable) ... _looks like the 4.14.y branch is up to 4.14.17 so you might get lucky_

Comment: I think there was no `4.14.y` branch. I used `rpi-4.14.y`.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant - `rpi-4.14.y` - see link I posted.

Answer (score 0):

If you still have the problem, now the official raspberry pi kernel repository has a branch for the [Preempt-RT](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/tree/rpi-4.14.y-rt) patched kernel version. You don't need to patch the "vanilla" kernel anymore. That means, you don't need to find a match between the kernel version and the rt patch version. Additionally, some other patches are included.

I wrote a [tutorial](https://lemariva.com/blog/2018/02/raspberry-pi-rt-preempt-tutorial-for-kernel-4-14-y) and made some [performance](https://lemariva.com/blog/2018/02/raspberry-pi-rt-preempt-vs-standard-kernel-4-14-y) tests. There are still some problems with the usb/lan irqs. I'm making some tests with the RPi 3 B+, I will publishing them this week.

Comment: Well, I have already tried that weeks ago without success. Though I used the official build instructions as found here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/building.md
and I simply used the rpi-4.14.y-rt branch instead. That should already have everything built in and even generate the right config automatically. Or do you see a problem with that?

Comment: No, there is no problem with that, it is almost the same procedure that I explained in my post. The deployment is different. As I said, the Preempt-RT is now a branch of the official repository, and you don't need to match the kernel version with the RT patch anymore. If you are using the LAN/USB you will have a problem with the IRQ39 (USB int), and you need to add these options: dwc_otg.fiq_enable=0 dwc_otg.fiq_fsm_enable=0 dwc_otg.nak_holdoff=0 to the /boot/cmdline.txt. Otherwise, the rpi freezes. But a prob. remains: You lose about 15% of the CPU performance, because of the interruption.